How can Delete new windows update file that are not installed
SO I see that temp files are taking 23GB of space

but when I try to go and clean it, it doesn't delete the files,
how can I delete that 19gb update file
.

I would just run the Disk Cleanup tool as an Administrator to clean up Windows Update.  You can also run Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup and Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase to clean up updates but that prevents you from being able to uninstall those updates. My suggestion just wait 14 days and Windows will automatically cleanup that data. Trying to manage WinSxS will prevent common troubleshooting solution if you experience a problem. If Windows is not installed on a large enough disk I suggest installing a larger disk.

You can try and delete you "C:\$Windows.~BT" folder, you would need to open Options for Folders(under View) and check "Hidden items".
For second part, to copletly clean your updates folder, open elevated CMD and paste all lines at once(or one by one);
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits

It wont do harm if you reset your pc after executing thee commands, then run check for update again.
When update is done, you can delete 2 renamed.old folders.
